# Fragment crash when click on item in listview

Tags: java, android

when i touch an item in the listView, the app crash

here's the logcat

> 2020-03-15 20:26:50.123 19174-19174/com.zeroXmohamed.TN19 E/Minikin:
>   Could not get cmap table size! 2020-03-15 20:26:50.158
>   19174-19202/com.zeroXmohamed.TN19 E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager:
>   MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist! 2020-03-15 20:26:54.323
>   19174-19174/com.zeroXmohamed.TN19 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.zeroXmohamed.TN19, PID: 19174
>       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x3
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:410)
>           at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:465)
>           at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:328)
>           at com.zeroXmohamed.TN19.fragment.ChercheFragment$1.onItemClick(ChercheFragment.java:48)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:321)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1217)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3203)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4151)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)

here's the code

```
package ...
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zeroXmohamed.TN19.R;


public class ChercheFragment extends Fragment {
    String countryList[] = {"India", "China", "australia", "Portugle", "America", "NewZealand"};
    private ListView simpleList;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cherche, container,
                false);
        simpleList= rootView.findViewById(R.id.ListC);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryList);
        simpleList.setAdapter(adapter);


        simpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                    int position, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

with:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

The version of `makeText()` that takes an `int` as the second parameter is expecting that `int` to be a string resource ID. Yours is not. So, you need to convert `position` to a `String` yourself.

Comment: that worked, thank you, i was trying to fix it for about 30 minutes, appreciate your help, i'll accept your answer in 10 minutes, that's what they said

Comment: @MohamedJawadi: Glad it worked! BTW, a small favor: in the future, please consider formatting your stack traces as source code, rather than as quoted text. Stack traces are *much* easier to read when formatted like source code.

Comment: i'll next time :)